# Loading Xml File Into Section, Key and Value Collection

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

We have a settings file which is basically Xml that we are extending for pluggable modules we are writing. Basically we want to use our existing Xml settings but allow extension methods to be written on them.  Long story short if we had an Xml file like so:

```
<Settings>

    <SettingsOne Key1_1="Value1"
                 Key1_2="Value2" />
    <SettingsTwo Key2_1="Value1"
                 Key2_2="Value2" />


</Settings>
```

How could we load this as an collection of SettingsEntry where SettingsEntry looked like so:

```
public class SettingsEntry
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Where Section would be "SettingsOne", Key would be "Key1_1" and Value would be "Value1".

Is this even possible or am I going down a dark path?

EDIT:

OK the suggestion of Linq to Xml was a life save, I was trying to do this with XmlSerializer!  Below is what I have so far, is there a way to turn this into a single select rather than two like I have below:

```
var root = XElement.Load(pathToXml);

  var sections = from el in root.Elements()
            select el.Name;

  List<SettingsEntry> settings = new List<SettingsEntry>();

  foreach (var item in sections)
  {
    var attributes = from el in root.Elements(item).Attributes()
                     select new SettingsEntry()
                     {
                       Section = item.LocalName,
                       Key = el.Name.LocalName,
                       Value = el.Value
                     };
    settings.AddRange(attributes);
  }

  return settings;
```

EDIT 2:

This seems to work.

```
   var sections = from el in root.Elements()
                 from a in root.Elements(el.Name).Attributes()
                 select new SettingsEntry()
                 {
                   Section = el.Name.LocalName,
                   Key = a.Name.LocalName,
                   Value = a.Value
                 };
```

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible - I suggest you try LINQ to XML. Think of query of `from element in doc.Root.Elements from attribute  in element.Attributes() select ...` Then ask a more detailed question if you have problems :)

Comment: Show what code you have and I will help you solve the problem. Put forth a little effort and I will help you.

Comment: Thank you Jon that was really helpful and pushed me down the right path, apologies Calvin, if I had come up with anything even remotely working I would have posted it but I went down the wrong direction entirely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in one LINQ query like this :

```
var attributes = from attribute in root.Elements().Attributes()
                 select new SettingsEntry()
                 {
                   Section = attribute.Parent.Name.LocalName,
                   Key = attribute.Name.LocalName,
                   Value = attribute.Value
                 };
return attributes.ToList();
```

Comment: OK this is better than what I came up with, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var xml = @"
 <Settings>
   <SettingsOne Key1_1= ""Value1"" Key1_2= ""Value1""></SettingsOne>
   <SettingsTwo Key2_1= ""Value1"" Key2_2= ""Value1""></SettingsTwo>
 </Settings>"

var root = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var q = root.Elements("Settings").Descendants();

List<SettingsEntry> settings = (from el in root.Elements("Settings").Descendants()
                 select new SettingsEntry()
                 {
                   Section = el.Name.ToString(),
                   Key = el.FirstAttribute.Value,
                   Value = el.LastAttribute.Value
                 }).ToList();
```

You might have to play with it a little to get the exact Object you want, but this is a serious push in the right direction.